# update user interface when orientation on starling

Tags: actionscript-3, user-interface, orientation, starling-framework

i build a mobile project using starling and feathersUI , when orientation device , updating user interface is very slow , where is the problem , how can i improve the speed of updating user interface ?

Comment: when you mean slow, do you mean the orientation_change event is slow to fire, or it fires and the subsequent ui update is slow?

Comment: You need to be more precise when asking questions. Providing a code sample is even better. Otherwise, its very hard to provide a sensible answer.